# ArrayField not recognized?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ArrayField'
```

Here is the relevant code segment:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class TypeStatistics(models.Model):
    bots_array = models.ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), blank=True)
```

Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two things, first make sure that you are using Django version >= 1.8 then change the following line:

```
bots_array = models.ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), blank=True)
```

to

```
bots_array = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), blank=True)
```

the django.db.models does not have an `ArrayField` but  you have imported `ArrayField` from contrib postgresql so that's what you should be using.

Comment: `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField`